# create/edit template form on Angular 6

Tags: angular6

I'm trying to created form following Template-driven Froms Angular 6 quide.

Lets say I have a form with two fields and appropriate model:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" [(ngModel)]="model.id">
<input type="text" name="user" required [(ngModel)]="model.user">
```

In case if I'll try to run such application in `create` mode I'll receive an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

because my model still not created.

I know that I can create model in `edit` mode by fetching data from web service but in case of `create` mode I can't create `model` object becase `user` property is required:

```
export class Form {
    constructor(
        public id: number | undefined,
        public user: User
    ) {

    }
}
```

What did i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `model.id` || `model.name` but only `id` || `name`

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" [(ngModel)]="id">
<input type="text" name="user" required [(ngModel)]="user">
```

Also you have to import

`import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';`

to your `app.module.ts`

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

---

[Example](https://codepen.io/Chiffie/pen/aRbOpz):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <input type="text" name="id" [(ngModel)]="id"><br>
   <input type="text" name="user" required [(ngModel)]="user">

   <div>Outputs for id: {{id}}</div>
   <div>Outputs for user: {{user}}</div>

    <!-- this will have same result --> 

   <div>Outputs for id: {{this.id}}</div>
   <div>Outputs for user: {{this.user}}</div>

   <hr/>

   <button (click)="setUser('Dave')">Change username to Dave</button>
  `
})
class AppComponent {  
  id = 'a';
  user = 'b';

  setUser(name: string) {
    this.user = name;
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me and I don't understand how it should work. Are `id` and `name` somehow related to the model? It could work in case if `id` and `name` will be properties of FormComponent class. Then after form submit I can get values from `this.id` and `this.name` but these variables are not related to the model.

Comment: @Vich They are related to component you are using. NgModel is angular property that is behing the scenes watches changes from html to js value (in component) and vice versa. In practice it means if you change value in input that has `ngmodel` property it will be changed in component. I'm sending you codepen that should help understanding that in edit.

Comment: OK, so in case of `edit` for we have a model immediately but in case of `create` form only after form submit. Seems that guide https://angular.io/guide/forms is a little bit misleading when you start to learn Angular. Thanks, Chiffre!

Comment: I mean that only after form submit we can create instance of model (`Form` class) using values of `this.id`, `this.user` properties, since before that we don't have value for required property `user`. So, this approach require to have dupliate properties in FormComponent which are optional and in model which are required? It looks odd.

Comment: Well you don't have to duplicate anything you have at least two options. 1. you can wrap it into component (if thats not an overkill) and pass it as `@Input`. or you can use something like `*ngIf="iHaveAnUserAndImShowingInputs"` (you will wrap your inputs into `ng-containter` with that `*ngIf`. Also I'm sorry for taking so long to respond.